# 'Edit all in scope' in VS code

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code

How do I re-name all occurrences of a variable within the current scope. I have other variables in the document named the same, but I just want re-name the ones within a specific function

Comment: As far as I recall there's a function called just that 'edit all in scope'. So, I figure people using Xcode may have miss using that feature in vs code and may have found a way to 'edit all in scope'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For VS Code on windows you can press F2 or right click and select 'rename symbol'.

Answer (score 0):

'rename symbol' is also present in mac and I guess it works the same. However, finding it is not intuitive since you just have to press `cmd + /` in most Mac apps to find the command you are looking for. In VS Code you find your commands in the 'pallet'